# Flutter app does not work on a real iOS device (white screen)

Tags: ios, flutter

Created a test application `flutter create hello_world`.
`flutter run` on the ios simulator launches the application perfect - it works!
But when launched on a real iOS device, appears windows the "Local Network" -> press "allow", and after only white screen.

`iOS 14.7.1`

`Xcode 12.5.1`

`Signing & Capabilities - no error`

```
flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5 20G71 darwin-x64, locale
    ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/incognito/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (4 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/incognito/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 mini (mobile) • 1CE9DEC7-D645-4C14-A3A5-79C4B1C8AB9F • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.107
    ! Error: iPhone No Name is busy: Waiting for Device. Xcode will continue
      when iPhone No Name is finished. (code -10)
```

Xcode console

```
2021-07-30 01:27:14.959824+0300 Runner[440:12621] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-07-30 01:27:15.028878+0300 Runner[440:12621] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
2021-07-30 01:27:15.028922+0300 Runner[440:12621] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
2021-07-30 01:27:15.076411+0300 Runner[440:12621] Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file
2021-07-30 01:27:15.088662+0300 Runner[440:12868] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
2021-07-30 01:27:15.088704+0300 Runner[440:12868] [VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(170)] Could not prepare isolate.
2021-07-30 01:27:15.088835+0300 Runner[440:12868] [VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(382)] Could not create root isolate.
2021-07-30 01:27:15.088861+0300 Runner[440:12868] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(576)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
2021-07-30 01:27:15.115109+0300 Runner[440:12882] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:50825/Ibq99VrylBU=/
```

**UPDATE**

footprint for posterit:
Solution - delete the bin/cache directory in your Flutter installation directory, then run flutter doctor and try again.

Comment: Uninstall and rerun your app

Comment: what do you mean when you say "uninstall and rerun an application"?
I create a new (like hello world) application, launch the ready-made ones, the result is the same

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011405/xcode-ios-project-what-is-the-meaning-of-fopen-failed-and-invalidating-cache

Comment: Running `flutter build ios` in the Flutter project directory resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

footprint for posterit: Solution - delete the bin/cache directory in your Flutter installation directory, then run flutter doctor and try again.

Comment: Tried. It didn't work.