# Fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a large project that has several Core Data containers.
When you first open the application on the simulator or on a real device, this error pops up in the debugger.

[image: Error - Fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)]

> fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
> Errors found! Invalidation cache...

However, my app works perfectly without any crashes and I ignored this error for a long time. Today I'm looking all day to solve this issue.

What exactly is the reason for this error is not so easy to follow. Now I created a new little project and started configuring Core Data. And I got this error again.
It was possible to trace the cause of this error through the logs of the real device.
Here's confirmation that Core Data is the culprit.

[image: CoreData Error]

The error appears only at the first launch of the application, and despite it, the application with Core Data works perfectly - all data is stored in Core Data and retrieved from it.

---

**My guesses...**

> fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

I assume that when the application is launched for the first time, the SQLite file simply does not exist yet and that is why this error pops up, but this file is created and everything works.
I would like to note that this error does not appear when the application is launched again, since the SQLite file has already been created.

---

**What I have already done for the solution.**

- Cmd + shift + K - does not solve this problem.
- I saw on Stackoverflow that this error appeared to users due to the use of Metal API - I have the Metal API validation technology disabled.
- The check for the creation of the CoreData file through the debug panel is also checked. Like I said, everything works great.
- The error appears on two MacBooks with Xcode 14.3.1 and Xcode 15 Beta 8, on Ventura and Sonoma, as well as on all simulators and real devices.
- For testing and checking, a new project was created on which this problem also exists.

---

**Testing CoreData…**

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

final class UserEventsCoreDataManager {

    static let instance = UserEventsCoreDataManager()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "UserEventsCoreDataContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading CoreData: \(error)")
            }
        }
    
        context = container.viewContext
    }

    func save() {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved successfully!")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving CoreData. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

final class UserEventsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let dataManager = UserEventsCoreDataManager.instance
   
    @Published var categories: [UserEventCategoryEntity] = []

    init() {
        fetchCategories()
    }
    
    func fetchCategories() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<UserEventCategoryEntity>(entityName: "UserEventCategoryEntity")
        
        do {
            categories = try dataManager.context.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching Categories: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addCategory() {
        let newCategory = UserEventCategoryEntity(context: dataManager.context)
        newCategory.categoryTitle = "My Parties"
        newCategory.categoryType = "parties"
        newCategory.events = []
        save()
        
    }
    
    func addHoliday() {
        let newEvent = UserEventItemEntity(context: dataManager.context)
        newHoliday.eventTitle = "AVB / ASOT 1000"
        newHoliday.categories = categories[0]

        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        categories.removeAll()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.dataManager.save()
            self.fetchCategories()
        }
    }
}
```

Open to any suggestions on this issue.

Comment: Does [Xcode iOS project: What is the meaning of "fopen failed" and "Invalidating cache..." at start of console log when running debug build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65011405/20386264) answer your question?

Comment: @BenzyNeez

Hi Benzy Neez. No, it didn't solve my problem. As I said, when I discovered this problem in my base project, I even created a new project to test it and it also has this problem. In the newly created project, I again had a similar problem related to CoreData, although everything works perfectly, the error only appears at the first launch of the program and, as I described above, concerns CoreData, and not the project build as a whole, because the project is coming together perfectly.

Comment: @BenzyNeez

Yes, I saw this post. However, as I wrote above... I already tried - Cmd + shift + K - does not solve this problem. I also have Metal API validation disabled.

Comment: Have you noticed any problems in how your app works or is it only these console messages?

Comment: @TomHarrington Hi tom! I had no problems with the app. The above error appeared as a console message only the first time the program was launched. I found a solution to this problem. A little later I will try to describe it. Maybe this will help someone else...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to solve this problem.

The culprit of the specified message in the console when the application starts for the first time is the .drawingGroup() modifier in SwiftUI. This modifier stores your view in memory as an image so the app doesn't have to recompile it every time. This solution is good and your app runs smoothly on older iPhone versions, despite the fact that it uses more RAM. However, at the first start of the application in memory, the render of your view has not yet been created, and therefore in some cases, we may receive such a message...

[image]

However, I don't understand why Xcode attributed this error to CoreData in the iPhone logs...

[image]

Regardless, my main app has been working fine and still is. But, after removing the .drawingGroup() modifier, the error disappeared when the application was first started. I believe this is a bug in SwiftUI's .drawingGroup() modifier, which is still unfixed. I think Apple should fix this bug. If the .drawingGroup() modifier is used when the application is first launched, if the view has not already been rendered into memory as an image, it just needs to be rendered. The developer should not see an uninformative message about the absence of some file, which is always generated when the program is first launched.

Be careful when using the .drawingGroup() modifier in SwiftUI and always test how it works the first time your app is launched. Most likely, your application will continue to work normally, your view will be compiled and saved in memory as an image, but this message may scare you and your team in the future. You can spend a lot of time looking for a bug like I did, which isn't exactly a bug. I think this message can be ignored... But in my case, I opted out of using the .drawingGroup() modifier in SwiftUI, so the error disappeared and the app started using less RAM.